# Breaking chained questions into individual ones when I am not sure of the approach?

Tags: discussion

I am learning a new technology and after the usual jumps through hoops with the docs I am stuck with some basic questions. I did not find similar ones asked before (more on this later). My problem can be broken into a chain of questions, similar to:

- how can I search for this specific item
- once I have the results, how can I efficiently reuse them in another query
- is it possible to aggregate the two queries
- can I directly create an index with the answers

(with examples of data to search for and what i discovered so far (not too much, unfortunately)).

These questions can be broken into individual ones. Since they are fairly basic ones and they neither have answers nor the docs obviously hint on how to approach them, I fear that the whole approach might be wrong.

The complete chain in one question could lead to either

- a set of answers for each individual point
- or a comment along the lines of "this is not how it should be done at all, it is better to ..."

I would lose the second perspective by dispatching the questions into individual posts.

Is it acceptable to break them down and provide the background with the intended chain of actions (and possibly links to the individual questions)?

Comment: Definitely have one question per question. If they're so basic, though, make sure they aren't answered already - either somewhere on SO, or elsewhere on the web...

Comment: @Pekka웃: well, the fact that I did not find an answer can mean that I did not look at the right place (this will be three days of searching and asking around - but the area is completely new to me) or that what I am trying to do should be done in another way (in the sense that asking "how to use dictionaries in x86 assembler?" will not show too much answers -- mine are not that disconnected and should make sense but, again, I am new to that particular field). I am currently leaning towards separate questions, as you suggested.

Comment: Step by step...

Comment: My experience is that asking questions about "the approach" doesn't yield good answers. Better to give concrete questions, with a bit of context about why you're trying to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First and foremost, 1 question per post unless they are so closely related that they can be answered by a single answer.

I cover the why in a lot more detail in my answer to [Can I ask only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post/222741#222741) on MSE, but the highlights are:

> If you ask more than 1 question per post, how are answerers (and the community at large) supposed to handle it?
>
> - What if they only have an answer to 1 question, but not the other? Should they answer it and not address both, or should they not answer because they can't answer both and deprive the community of a good response to a good question.
> - What if both questions are duplicate of other questions? Which one should be used as the duplicate target? No matter which one is picked people looking at the question will only be confused as the duplicate doesn't address the "other" question.
> - What if one question should be closed for any reason and the other shouldn't? Should we close it or leave it open.
>     What if I think one question is good and want to upvote it and the other is bad and want to downvote it?
> - What if someone finds your post via Google and thinks it will solve their problem, only to find all of the answers are about your other question?

---

As for how to proceed, don't ask all of the questions at the same time.  Since these apparently are a progressive series of question, start with the first question and wait until you get a solution, then move on to the 2nd and wait again, then asked the 3rd (and so on).

- Since the questions build on each other, the answers may too.  In the act of asking the question and reading responses via comments or answers, you might get learn some new concepts or keywords that help in your searching.  Maybe your 2nd question is a duplicate once you learn the new concepts and you can skip right to your 3rd question.
- You might even get enough info in the answer to the previous question that you can solve your next issue on your own, or you might change the approach enough that it would radically change the next question.
- Asking several questions at one time is dangerous.  What if, despite the fact that you think they are well written and complete, the community thinks otherwise.  Managing comments and downvotes, and trying to improve a poorly received question get compounded when you need to manage multiples.  At your current rep level, you are probably out of the danger zone of getting question banned, but you aren't completely safe (depending on your entire question history) and there is no sense tempting fate.  However, for someone with significantly less rep and fewer questions, this is an significant concern.

---

And for structuring the individual questions, limit the amount of meta commentary to what is absolutely necessary, so do not get into a long winded discussion about how long you have googled and how many of the API documents you have read.

Explain your core problem and provide relevant details, but avoid distracting the question with info not relevant to the question at hand, with one exception. In all of the questions, you should **briefly** explain your end goal (what you hope to achieve after asking all of your questions).  This is due to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  How do you know the multi-step approach your are taking is the correct one?  Maybe there is a better approach that is done in fewer steps or is a 1 step solution that is simpler than you thought.

And if you think the info contained in one of the previous questions is important to answering the current, then you can link to it in the next question and explain how it is related to the current problem, but don't include it just for the sake of including it.

Comment: The XY Problem was exactly my concern.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should post them as separate questions, one per problem.

> The complete chain in one question could lead to either
>
> - a set of answers for each individual point
> - or a comment along the lines of "this is not how it should be done at all, it is better to ..."

When you're done, you might want to check out [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), where they can answer things like "don't do it like that".

This is in addition to [psubsee2003's advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280099/3187556).

Answer (score 1):

First, *"One question per post"* is the mantra here. So I would push toward asking several questions.

*However*, I see several reasons that should refrain you from doing this on regular basis:

- The XY problem: having a step by step approach might put to much emphasis on how you have approached the problem. And not enough on *what* you are trying to achieve
- Private question: having too much context from previous questions to understand might lead to something I called "private questions". That is a question that could only be fully understandable by those who have already read the preceding one.
- Feed the vampire: Even if it is probably not you case, such approach might lead to us doing all the asker work, step by step. Kind of "giv'me the codez" or "do-it-for-me" request. But not as visible as if it was posted as only one question.

As  a conclusion, both for your benefit and the community's one, I would encourage to *post one question at a time*, to *post only the questions that really need to be posted* and finally to *post questions as much decorrelated as you can from the other one*.

Comment: In my case it was the XY problem: not knowing the technology I was afraid that each question taken separately leads to good answers, but that would not solve correctly the problem due to a flaw in the assumptions. Thanks.